# how to change the text in element via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button of download,when clicked it should change the text of the element span but I have problem in ajax part

after clicking it will show me a little button and the text will not change

here is my html

```
//somecode
    <span class="num">Downloaded:<?php echo $downloadcount;?></span>
     </td></tr>
     </table>
     </div>
<button type = "button" class="button" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="dl">
    <a href='./mp3/<?php echo basename($filename);?>'>Download</a>
</button>
         </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

here is my ajax:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() 
        {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var name = $(this).attr("name");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);
        if(name=='dl')
        {
        $(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "download_number.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,

           success: function(html)
           {
//THE PROBLEM IS HERE
            $(".num").text(html);

          }  });

        }
        });
        });
```

I also tried `$(".num").html(html);`

Comment: after clicking it will show me a little button and the text will not change

Comment: What you get if you do alert(html) or console.log(html) ?

Comment: it doesn't show me alertbox I tried now

Comment: What's in the `download_number.php` file?

Comment: @nikparsa: Then the `success` callback isn't running. Try `error` instead of `success`.

Comment: put error callback and try if you are not getting error.

Comment: it shows me [ObjectXmlHttprequest] with error instead of success

Comment: can you try doing in $.ajax { data: {id : id}} instead of dataString

Comment: it shows nothing,I'm sure data string doesn't have problem because in div elements I have this code and it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put an `<a>` inside the `<button>` - the link will win over the button action [[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5T5ZE/1/)].

Beyond this, your code seems right.

Comment: but I want to download my file removing that will loose my file

Comment: Then why do you need both a link and a button? Stick with one and you're done ^^

Comment: Ok I think you need that for stats purpose - serve your files not via vanilla apache, but process them via PHP, save your stats then forward binary mp3 data.

Comment: when clicking the button I want user to download the file and with ajax simultaneously update the download number

Comment: I don''t know about vanila?! I am using wamp apache and the whole is with php what do u mean?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516779/setting-up-apache-to-serve-php-when-an-mp3-file-is-requested): you serve the mp3 file via PHP, but you may perform an update query before ^^

Comment: I will do it if it was the last resort

Comment: you were right thanks a lot,after editing a lot that people told me,and removing the link I thaught you're wrong but in my origin I removed the link and now it's working,Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

change datastring to this

```
var dataString = "{'id'="+ id+"}" ;
```

and add datatpe json...By doing so it may work....just guessing

```
datatype:'json', 
  success: function(html)
               {
               alert(html);
               // First see...what u r getting in response and then move forward

              }
```

Comment: it shows nothing just after a second show me my file ready to download

Comment: data string doesn't have problem as sure