# PHP Streaming MP3

Tags: php, mp3, header, filestream, readfile

I have a very similar situation to the person who asked:
[Can I serve MP3 files with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516661/can-i-serve-mp3-files-with-php)
Basically I am trying to protect mp3 files from direct download, so users have to go through php to get authenticated first.
Here's my code:

```
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
Header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
readfile($file);
```

Here's my problem: The file only plays a very small chunk of the beginning (via Quicktime in the browser) and then stops - Quicktime seems to think the *length of the file is only as long as the chunk it managed to download*. When I reload - it plays a slightly larger chunk - whatever it managed to download up to that point.

Is that a problem in the headers I am sending? How would I stream such a file?
Is it a problem if an swf is reading from that file?

Thanks!

---

**Thank you guys for all the answers. Although none of these things were exactly what solved the problem, many of them sent me in the right direction. Much appreciated.
For the full solution see my answer below**

Comment: I presume you don't have that typo ("Header") in your real code?  Also, you don't need the X-Pad hack.  This is only necessary for ancient Netscape (see http://george.hotelling.net/90percent/geekery/why_is_apache_sending_a_xpad_header.php).  You don't need Content-Transfer-Encoding, and you should only specify Content-Type once (audio/mpeg is fine).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: PHP functions are case-insensitive, so it's only a consistency issue. The Content-Type may be the real issue here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what did the trick.

```
$dir = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/protected_content";
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$file = $dir."/".$filename;

$extension = "mp3";
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";

if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-type: {$mime_type}');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Comment: You might want to do some validation/sanitising on $_GET['file'] before reading it...

Comment: I check if the file exists `if(file_exists($file)){`... Is that what you meant?

Comment: No he didn't mean that. Think for yourself, what happens if someone tries this http://yoursite.com/yourscript.php?file=../../../home/someonesgirlfriend/secretdiary.doc

Comment: Its great but its not seekable !!

Comment: To make it seekable just add the following header line, but no support for resume in this code.
**`header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');`**
If you need the Content-Transfer-Encoding
better try to use `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked");`

Comment: I checked this code in Google Chrome and Download Window appears unless $mime_type be changed to $mime_type = "audio/mpeg";

Answer (score 1):

You can try [HTTP chunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Set the "Transfer-Encoding" header to "chunked", then output the size of each chunk before sending it. End each chunk size and chunk with a CRLF.

For anything more complex, I recommend using a streaming server, such as [Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand out:

1. You've got a `Content-Length` set. If you server is set to automatically gzip your output, this can mess with things. Try turning off `Content-Length` and see if that fixes it.
2. You've got about a thousand `Content-Type`s set. Since it's Mp3 that you're serving, just use `audio/mpeg`. You can effectively get rid of the whole last `header()` command. It's easy to get carried away with HTTP headers.

Try it out and let us know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

if your server is running on apache or lighty, i would suggest you look into x-sendfile

http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/

this allows you to handle authentication in your php application, but let's your webserver handle the transmission of the file. the performance improvement you gain should be a nice additional benefit

Answer (score 0):

Remove `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");` And you'll be set!

Answer (score 0):

For these solution you also need to configure xsendfile in apache (mod_xsendfile) or nginx HttpSecureLinkModule - they will give you exact mp3, so browser will play it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Applying all these solutions, which are valid to hide the original path and filename, unfortunately doesn't prevent from unauthorized download.
Indeed the client (on my case: Chrome) downloads the file.

Here the lines I put on my server:

```
<?php
$dir = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/mp3";
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$file = $dir."/".$filename;

$extension = "mp3";
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";

if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-type: {$mime_type}');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

with or without the line

```
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

the final result doesn't change
The directory /mp3 is located into

```
/home/myuser/
```

(thus /home/myuser/mp3)
and the public HTML directory is

```
/home/myuser/public_html
```

thus calling my domain and giving

```
/player.php?file=music.mp3
```

it downloads a file called music.mp3 with all the original content.