# Make mp3 seekable PHP

Tags: php, html

I did this PHP script

```
    $file_name = 'sample.mp3';

    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');

    $opts     = array('http' =>
                      array(
                          'method'           => 'GET',
                          'protocol_version' => 1.1,
                      )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
    $stream   = fopen($file_name, 'rb', FALSE, $context);
    $metadata = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
    $data     = stream_get_contents($stream);
    print($data);
    fclose($stream);
```

It could stream mp3 media successfully but I'm not able to seek the mp3 file that get played also in html5 `video` tags are not able to extract metadata from it, please tell me where I'm doing wrong and how to make this process work, thanks

Answer (score 25):

Here try this, supports partial downloads and seeking for any filesize, also now correctly works in chrome:

```
<?php 
$file_name = './sample.mp3';
stream($file_name, 'audio/mpeg');

/**
 * Stream-able file handler
 *
 * @param String $file_location
 * @param Header|String $content_type
 * @return content
 */
function stream($file, $content_type = 'application/octet-stream') {
    @error_reporting(0);

    // Make sure the files exists, otherwise we are wasting our time
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }

    // Get file size
    $filesize = sprintf("%u", filesize($file));

    // Handle 'Range' header
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
        $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];
    }elseif($apache = apache_request_headers()){
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($apache as $header => $val){
            $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;
        }
        if(isset($headers['range'])){
            $range = $headers['range'];
        }
        else $range = FALSE;
    } else $range = FALSE;

    //Is range
    if($range){
        $partial = true;
        list($param, $range) = explode('=',$range);
        // Bad request - range unit is not 'bytes'
        if(strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes'){ 
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            exit;
        }
        // Get range values
        $range = explode(',',$range);
        $range = explode('-',$range[0]); 
        // Deal with range values
        if ($range[0] === ''){
            $end = $filesize - 1;
            $start = $end - intval($range[0]);
        } else if ($range[1] === '') {
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = $filesize - 1;
        }else{ 
            // Both numbers present, return specific range
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = intval($range[1]);
            if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) $partial = false; // Invalid range/whole file specified, return whole file
        }
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
    }
    // No range requested
    else $partial = false; 

    // Send standard headers
    header("Content-Type: $content_type");
    header("Content-Length: " . ($partial ? $length : $filesize));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    // send extra headers for range handling...
    if ($partial) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize");
        if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'rb')) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit;
        }
        if ($start) fseek($fp,$start);
        while($length){
            set_time_limit(0);
            $read = ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
            $length -= $read;
            print(fread($fp,$read));
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    //just send the whole file
    else readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works brilliantly when I copy the PHP files address into VLC. However if I add the link to a HTML5 audio tag, or JWplayer it doesn't recognize the stream. I get errors in my log stating:  PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent. Thank you.

Comment: @joshkrz - You should make sure you do not send any output(whitespace, html) before setting headers, the error your getting will tell you where your outputting.

Comment: Apparently I am outputting on line 89 [   print($download_data_chunk);   ]. The error just tells me all the lines that have headers set within your code. The strange thing is if I type a direct link to this script it shows a Google Chrome MP3 player but doesn't do anything. I don't get any errors when I do this. The script doesn't have any extra echos or prints.

Comment: @joshkrz the Exception lines will echo out onto the page, im not sure how your calling it, but you should wrap it in a `try{}catch(){}` to catch the exceptions.

Comment: I have tried this in Firefox and it works perfectly in the native MP3 player (via direct link) and my inline js players. It doesn't come across like a browser issue though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46595/discussion-between-loz-cherone-and-joshkrz)

Comment: @joshkrz function is now fixed for chrome, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @LozCherone. I've been trying to get this to work with an audio tag and serving the mp3 from a PHP script, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213180/safari-doesnt-show-duration-of-mp3-served-from-php-correctly Using this function seems to work locally even with Safari, but on the remote VPS it still doesn't work. It seems that on the VPS only the first bytes=0-1 request comes through and there is no followup request to get the actual audio data. Locally that does happen so I'm really at a loss here. Any ideas?

Comment: @Loz Cherone Content-Length should be the length you send. That is not always filesize($file).

Comment: It'd be nice to credit the person [you copied your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4451376/84631) from.

Comment: Yes, this is genius! Thank you

Comment: Actually (made a suggested edit but now I can't undo), I think the Content-Length should be more like: `header("Content-Length: " . ($range ? ($end - $start + 1) : $filesize));`.

Comment: Thank so much for this answer - life saver! One thing: I had to add ```header("Content-Length: " . ( $end - $start ) );``` in the if($partial) block, to prevent chrome from complaining about a content length mismatch ```net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH``` -- edit: as @B.F and @Agamemnus already pointed out, sorry!

Comment: Thank you very much. It works in all browsers except Mac Safari and iPhone Safari. After applying the suggestion by @Agamemnus it now works for Safari.

Comment: Noticed an issue, though. When the MP3 play-time is very long (e.g. 40 minutes or so), it would take very long to launch the player. Still looking for solutions.

Comment: This does not work for the latest Chrome. I'm using Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit).  Worked for previous versions of Chrome.

Comment: This works great in all desktop browsers but fails on ios Safari - audio doesn't play. Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: @spice I checked the code on IOS safari & IOS chrome, it works without problem

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully fix your problem, follow this method.

What you need to do is use `readfile()` and set `file_exists()` so that you can tell you're opening the correct file.

```
$extension = "mp3";
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";

if(file_exists($file_name)){
    header('Content-type: ' . $mime_type);
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file_name));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $file_name);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($file_name);
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358253/php-streaming-mp3)

Comment: I want it buffered, how could I?

Comment: As stated above, this doesn't have a `Content-Range`; in Chrome, it is not currently possible (5 years later) to set the currentTime without that.

Comment: header('Content-typ... missing double quotes and solution doesn't work