# Make MP3 seekable in php

Tags: php, http-headers, mp3, seek

I am using below code to get a MP3 file via PHP.
My problem is the MP3 which this code produces is not seeking.

```
@$filename = $_GET['q'].'.mp3';

if(file_exists($filename)){
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename);
header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($filename);
 }else{
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

It really becomes my headache to find a proper header or another  solution to make it possible to seek the MP3.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make mp3 seekable PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340276/make-mp3-seekable-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
header('Content-Disposition:inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```