# Php download and stream video at the same time

Tags: php, video, download, youtube, stream

I'm tying to make a php script to sownload video from youtube and stream it at the same time and this is my code ..

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

$vid_id = $_GET['vidId'];

if (!file_exists('../cache_files/youtube/' . $vid_id . '.mp4')) {
    $vid_info = file_get_contents('https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=' . $vid_id);
    parse_str($vid_info);
    $Array = explode(',', $url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
    foreach ($Array as $item) {
        parse_str($item);
        $format = trim(substr($type, 0, strpos($type, ';')));
        if ($format = 'video/mp4' && $quality == 'medium') {
            download($url, $vid_id);
            break;
        } else {
            echo $reason;
        }
    }
} else {
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile('../cache_files/youtube/' . $vid_id . '.mp4');
    exit;
}
function download($infile, $outfile)
{
    $chunksize = 100 * (1024 * 1024);
    $parts     = parse_url($infile);
    $i_handle  = fsockopen($parts['host'], 80, $errstr, $errcode, 5);
    $o_handle  = fopen('../cache_files/youtube/' . $outfile . '.mp4', 'wb');
    if ($i_handle == false || $o_handle == false) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
        $parts['path'] .= '?' . $parts['query'];
    }
    $request = "GET {$parts['path']} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: {$parts['host']}\r\n";
    $request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n";
    $request .= "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($i_handle, $request);
    $headers = array();
    while (!feof($i_handle)) {
        $line = fgets($i_handle);
        if ($line == "\r\n")
            break;
        $headers[] = $line;
    }
    $length = 0;
    foreach ($headers as $header) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Content-Length:') === 0) {
            $length = (int) str_replace('Content-Length: ', '', $header);
            break;
        }
    }
    $cnt = 0;

    while (!feof($i_handle)) {
        $buf = '';
        echo $buf = fread($i_handle, $chunksize);
        $bytes = fwrite($o_handle, $buf);
        if ($bytes == false) {
            return false;
        }
        $cnt += $bytes;
        if ($cnt >= $length)
            break;
    }
    fclose($i_handle);
    fclose($o_handle);
    if (file_exists('../cache_files/youtube/' . $outfile . '.mp4')) {
        if (!filesize('../cache_files/youtube/' . $outfile . '.mp4') > 1024) {
             unlink('../cache_files/youtube/' . $outfile . '.mp4');
        }
    }
    return $cnt;
}
```

i use it like this

```
<video controls autoplay>
<source src='http://127.0.0.1/youtube.video.grabber.php?vidId=BYi7Lc2aclY'>
</video>
```

the "youtube.video.grabber.php" file now should start downloading the file to my disk and stream it to the client at the same time and it works but i can't move the video to the forward or the backward so i need to add some headers to this code like partial content and some other headers and here's the problem after adding the headers to the code it stops and won't work again .. so i wanna know how to add those headers to the this code or if you have a better solution to download and stream the file at the same time with the ability to move the video to the backward or the forward i will be grateful if you told me how .. thanks and sorry about my bad english

Comment: Your first problem ist that you're using `file_get_contents()` which loads the whole content of the video file first. But you have to read chunks and pass them directly to the browser. You can do this by using `fopen` or better CURL and an own stream wrapper implementation.

Comment: i'm using file_get_contents() to get the video_file_info to extract the video direct link from googlevideo server and pass it to the download function to download the video and stream it

Comment: Ou sorry didn't see that. Okay I think you have to implement the stream so that it is seekable. This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11341766/1652031

Comment: i think it's impossible to do that .. it's possible if the video on my local disk but i can't do it if the file on a remote server .. thanks for ur help

Comment: As far as the server who hosts the video also supports seekable it should be possible I guess.