# HTML5 audio from PHP script

Tags: php, html, audio, http-headers

I want to play audio which will be generated from a php script.

Client side:

```
<audio controls autoplay src="audio.php"></audio>
```

Server side:

```
$path = 'somefile.mp3';
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($path);
```

It plays, but I can't change current the time in the audio element. The range slider is not working.

[image: Result]

Comment: I think the reason is you must make audio file seekable. For example when user rewind audio file this player try to get partial content (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340276/make-mp3-seekable-php)

Comment: Thanks. My problem solved

Answer (score 4):

It is just missing a few things in the header in order for the seekbar to work. The Content-Length and Accept-Ranges. The HTML audio player needs them in order to build player seekbar.

Try this:

```
$path = 'somefile.mp3';
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile($path);
```