# Pure Javascript html5 audio change currentTime not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm building an audio player but having problems with Chrome.
If I try to jump ahead on the play time Chrome just restarts the clip. I probably just need to be pointed in the right direction. I'm thinking I need to waiting for buffer to load first or something.

Here's the url to the working file:
https://www.christart.com/music/

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How is your code now? Maybe if we see it, we can point you the problem, or help you improve it

Comment: Christian, I submitted the url.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9565178/7422994) answer, maybe the problem is the server. If you create the `audio` tag without any javascript, the problem remains, so that answer maybe is a step to the solution.

Comment: Christian, you're definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11341766/6780939 to deliver my mp3s. I now works with chrome, but now no works mac/IE or iphone. Any suggestions?