# Workbox pre-cached audio with range requests router fails to play in Chrome when served from Firebase

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting, workbox

### Background

I have created a PWA test project to find out how to get audio caching working with [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox), 
including scrub/seek using the [range requests plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-range-requests).

I want the app to precache all audio and for this audio to be playable offline, including scrub/seek.

Pre-caching the audio can be done in one of two ways:

1. Using [Workbox injectManifest](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-cli#injectmanifest).
2. By manually adding audio files to a cache using `cache.add(URL)`

But audio files cached with the first method (injectManifest) will not scrub/seek because the Workbox pre-cache does not
support range request headers. So you need to put a range request enabled router in front of the 
pre-cache for audio files if you want to be able to scrub through/seek within a cached audio file.

### Problem

Pre-cached audio with a range requests enabled router will play and scrub/seek fine in Chrome and Firefox when app is served 
from localhost but fails to play in Chrome when served from Firebase.

I see the same error for all audio files that are pre-cached with a range requests router in front of them:

```
Router is responding to: /media/audio/auto-pre-cached.mp3
Using CacheOnly to respond to '/media/audio/auto-pre-cached.mp3'
    No response found in the 'act-auto-pre-cache-wbv4.3.1-actv0.0.1' cache.
    The FetchEvent for "https://daffinm-test.firebaseapp.com/media/audio/auto-pre-cached.mp3" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.
    CacheOnly.mjs:115 Uncaught (in promise) no-response: The strategy could not generate a response for 'https://daffinm-test.firebaseapp.com/media/audio/auto-pre-cached.mp3'.
        at CacheOnly.makeRequest (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-strategies.dev.js:343:15)
```

Chrome versions tried:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
```

The files are present in the Workbox caches. The only difference I can see between locahost and Firebase is in the cached response headers:

**Localhost**

```
cache-control: max-age=3600
content-length: 3770956
content-type: audio/mpeg; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 09:37:03 GMT
etag: "12456134-3770956-"2019-09-29T20:05:00.314Z""
last-modified: Sun, 29 Sep 2019 20:05:00 GMT
server: ecstatic-2.2.2
```

**Firebase**

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=3600
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 3686565
content-type: audio/mpeg
date: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 11:47:43 GMT
etag: 267d9ec42517198c01e2cad893f1b14662a2d91904bc517aeda244c30358457c
last-modified: Mon, 07 Oct 2019 03:48:25 PDT
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: x-fh-requested-host, accept-encoding
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-served-by: cache-lhr7363-LHR
x-timer: S1570448862.315027,VS0,VE1472
```

Firefox works fine in both cases.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0
```

### Code

You can find the code for the test app here including a full description of the test setup, expectations and results:

https://github.com/daffinm/audio-cache-test

And the app is currently deployed on Firebase here if you want to take a look:

https://daffinm-test.firebaseapp.com/

### Question

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here and why the pre-cached audio with range request routers are failing to play in Chrome? Is this a Chrome bug and/or a Workbox mis-configuration and/or a Firebase configuration issue - or something completely different? (I have contacted Firebase support and they are being very helpful but are currently unable to enlighten me).

Comment: And yes, this question is an extension to [one I asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903010/cannot-scrub-scroll-through-jplayer-audio-when-mp3-is-cached-by-workbox) but it is different and IMO warranted a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presence of the [`Vary` header](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/understanding-vary-header/) in the Firebase responses sounds like the culprit. By default, the Cache Storage API will use the `Vary` header when determining whether or not there's a cache match. You can override this default behavior by passing in `{ignoreVary: true}` when querying the Cache Storage API. Workbox [supports this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1550) as an option you can provide when creating your strategy, via the [`matchOptions` parameter](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.strategies.CacheOnly.html#CacheOnly).

It looks like you're [already passing in `ignoreSearch: true`](https://github.com/daffinm/audio-cache-test/blob/78048a9b400ce4761b93e433b5fe932cb114b297/www/sw.js#L75-L77), so you can just add `ignoreVary: true` alongside that.

Comment: Thanks Jeff! That finally seems to have fixed it. The demo app is now working as expected in Chrome. Code in github and Firebase updated. I do hope others find this useful too. Cheers - Miles

Comment: One thought. Could the Workbox logging be improved to explain why a strategy could not generate a response? Is this possible?