# How to stream video on homeserver using php?

Tags: php, video, xampp, html5-video

I try to make a website on my homeserver, which can play videos.
I use XAMPP for Windows 7.2.33.
PHP snippet of function:

```
?>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mb-4">
   <video src="<?=$src?>" autoplay controls></video>
 </div>
</div>
<?php
```

$src is the correct path of the mp4 file.

```
$src = "F:/Avatar - The Last Airbender/s01/e01.mp4"
```

The video player appears, but does not play the file.
I have tried the  tag in a simple .html file, and it worked out of the xampp, but not in the xampp's htdocs dir.
[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUbhg.png)
I assume there is something with apache, but I don't know.
Do you have any idea what the problem is, or how should I stream videos from php?

Comment: What's the value of `$src`? Its either not found, or not a supported format

Comment: @LawrenceCherone value of $src :"F:/Avatar - The Last Airbender/s01/e01.mp4"
When I tried in a simple html file, not using xampp it worked. Open with xampp like http://localhost/index.html does not work. The video player appears, but does not play the file.

Comment: probably you have an error in your console. The link should be a URL not a file path.

Comment: yeah as ADyson said *the link should be a URL not a file path*, you would need to move the files into htdocs directory or mount H: as a directory in htdocs, or make a script which proxies it from that directory (not trivial if you want seeking support, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340276/make-mp3-seekable-php/11341766#11341766)). basically if done over HTTP, the file has to be in an accessible location within the webroot

Comment: **(1)** Test by copying the file `e01.m4`to your same place as your PHP file and just set as `$src = "e4.mp4";` ... Does it work now? **(2)** Just **don't use spaces** in a URL path (it gives guaranteed problems). If you need a folder name with gaps then maybe use underscores in the name _eg:_ `Avatar_-_The_Last_Airbender` as example

Comment: Thank you guys!!
As ADyson said, it should be a URL not a file path. And LawrenceCherone 's suggestions are pretty good.