# Read audio file from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jwplayer

I am using this code in jw player to play audio.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player_1234').setup({
   file: 'http://localhost/media.php?media_id=1822',
   type: 'm4a', 
   width: '100%',
   plugins: {},
   aspectratio: '16:9',
  fallback: 'false',
   primary: jwplayer.utils.isChrome() ? "html5" : "html5"
   });
</script>
```

Here, media.php file returns the the proper content-type `audio header()` using `readfile()`.

`Media.php` works fine when i directly enter in browser.

But jw player gives this error message **"Cannot read property 'sources' of undefined"** when page is loaded. How can I fix this error?

Comment: This is called spreaming. Problem is that the file is not being streamed, but it has to be downloaded first.

Comment: @M1K1O How to solve this?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358253/php-streaming-mp3

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this.

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer Can you guess what could be the problem?Video is playing fine in this case but audio is not.

Comment: My guess is that either the audio file is not encoded properly, or the mime type is wrong. However, I can't know for sure without seeing this in action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked when type is changed to mp4 instead of m4a

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('player_1234').setup({
   file: 'http://localhost/media.php?media_id=1822',
   type: 'mp4', 
   width: '100%',
   plugins: {},
   aspectratio: '16:9',
  fallback: 'false',
   primary: jwplayer.utils.isChrome() ? "html5" : "html5"
   });
</script>
```