# php mp3 downloads html file on android

Tags: php, android, html

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$download = './downloads/'.$mp3;

header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($download)); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
readfile($download);
?>
```

On android, once download starts, it downloads an unreadable htm file. $mp3 is like this: NAME.mp3. What may be wrong?

Comment: Where are you defining $mp3???post that code too

Comment: It's a MVC binded variable from controller. But basicaly it is: "name.mp3"

Comment: you just echo $mp3 before using it and check if you get NAME.mp3 as the output..

Comment: Long shot but have you tried any other mime types, audio/mp3?

Comment: thats a string right??

Comment: Same happens with: "Content-Type: audio/mp3"

Comment: Try removing the headers and see if you get any errors on output. You should see the source of the mp3 file as if you opened it in a text editor. That is fine, just look for any extra output. You should likely also check stuff like `file_exists($download)`.

Comment: Lal, yes it's a string.

Comment: Removing headers opens a random chunk of htm page.

Comment: "Content-type" is not "Content-Type"... Change and try...

Comment: No, has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, have you looked at your PHP error logs? This sounds to me like your server / dev environment doesn't have PHP running correctly.

I found this post relating, seems they were able to get it to work with some extra headers, that is if your PHP is working properly:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367506/2080324

Yes, but remember headers tell devices what type of file it is. Different devices will interpret different files in different ways. In the example I linked, he sets the mime-type as well as headers:

```
$dir = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/protected_content";
$filename = $_GET['file'];
$file = $dir."/".$filename;

$extension = "mp3";
$mime_type = "audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3";

if(file_exists($file)){
    header('Content-type: {$mime_type}');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $filename);
    header('X-Pad: avoid browser bug');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    readfile($file);
}else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Comment: They surely do. It downloads mp3 correctly on win enviroment.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, using that resulted in win's browser not working, having same behaviour.