# Is there possibility to run background audio from php without controls, with autoplay and no-cache?

Tags: php, audio

I would like to play information displayed on the screen in background. I am able to get mp3 stream using text to speech Microsoft REST API to store it and I tried:

A/ to use `<audio autoplay><source src='sound.mp3'>`.... It is working but I cannot find the way to disable caching.

B/ solution described at [PHP Streaming MP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358253/php-streaming-mp3/2367506#2367506). It is working but it starts video player. Is there a way how to modify code to start audio player with autoplay but without controls and styles?

Thank you for any help

Comment: What do you mean by _"It is working but it starts video player"_? Are you calling this script on its own now, not by using it as source for an audio element?

Comment: (The discussion under that other question has some hints on how to the set content-type, maybe you set it wrong the same way OP did there?)

Comment: _"It is working but I cannot find the way to disable caching."_ - and a normal run-of-the-mill cache buster, i.e. appending the current timestamp or a random value in the query string, did not work?

Comment: I know nothing about php however to put something like audio into the background perhaps you might try giving the audio rendering its own thread when will free up the main thread to continue yet permit the audio to rumble along in parallel