# PHP: Simple way to Limit File downloads to URLs with valid get parameters

Tags: php

I want users who visit my site with a valid URL (get parameter is checked in database)

to be able to download a file from the server while others who don't access the site with a valid URL aren't able to do so.

Currently i am able to do

```
if (isValid($get_param))
{
    print link to file
} else {    
    print some other message
}
```

This is fine but doesn't prevent someone from simply visiting the direct link to the file say `site.com/file.mp3`.

How do I prevent someone from being able to download the file in that manner but allow them download it if the URL has a valid get parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I serve MP3 files with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516661/can-i-serve-mp3-files-with-php)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that in your file permissions on the server.

Only allow the PHP code permissions to access that file.

Comment: You are not wrong in what you have said, but you have failed to answer what was asked :)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider moving your protected files outside of the web server document root to avoid the direct access, then using `readfile()` in combination with `header()` to force a download as shown in the first example on the [`readfile() manual page`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the link to it, try adding this code after the validation.

```
$file = "something.zip/pdf";

header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
@readfile($file);
```

This will just start the download directly and the user doesnt get to know where the file is coming from

Comment: This code doesnt depend of what type of file it is, it will work the same for text, zip, mp3 or any other file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to process your download in PHP, to prevent unauthorized access:

```
$file = "path/to/file.mp3";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename( $file ));
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg"); // you need the correct mime-type for your file
header("Content-Length: ". filesize( $file ) );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
exit;
```